# Reading json data in spring controller sent by angular 2 post

Tags: json, spring, angular

I actually find a solution but i think there is an easier way. I am trying to post a json data using angular2 and try to read it in the spring controller.

class is

```
export class EmovieCat{

    id:String = "test";
    rev:String;
    dataModelVersion:number = 99;

}
```

post code in angular 2

```
 this.emv  = new EmovieCat();
        this._http.post(this._url,JSON.stringify(this.emv)).subscribe(response =>{
            console.log(response.json());
        });
```

I am getting the json string like this.

```
BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.req.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String json = "";

        if(br != null){
            try {
                json = br.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

This way i can get the json string.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should this kind of controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method ={ RequestMethod.POST }, value ={ "/save/info" }, produces = { "application/json" })
public ResponseEntity<String> storeRedirectUrl(@RequestBody EmovieCat emc)
{
    //Here you have the emc object that is the JSON reversed in Java Object
}
```

In this case Spring is able in creating the Emoviecat object by using jackson marshaller API and you must only take care about the business logic